# Do we have to include the value corresponding to the cancelled factor in the range?

Tags: functions

> Range of the function:
>
> $f(x) = \dfrac{x-2}{x^3 + 2x^2 - 4x - 8}$ is equal to ?
>
> a) $[0,\infty)$
>
> b) $(0,\infty)$
>
> c) $(0,\infty) - \dfrac 1 {16}$
>
> d) $(0,\infty) - \dfrac 1 4$

So basically on factoring we get:

$f(x) = \dfrac{(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+2)^2}$

Thus,  $x = 2$ is not in domain.

So after cancelling $(x-2)s$ from numerator and denominator, the value corresponding to $x = 2$ should be removed from the range.

Now, it comes to me as a surprise that the answer given is option (b) instead of option (c).

Have I got my concepts wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although after cancelling you create a hole at $x = 2,$ there is another way to obtain $\frac{1}{16}$, namely, by setting $x = -6.$ Thus, $\frac{1}{16}$ is in the range. You do have the right idea though.

Answer (score 0):

$x=2$ is not in the domain, but $x=-6$ is.